# What are the ways to compare two SQL Server Databases containing system-versioned tables(temporal tables)?

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Server databases with the same schema. Source and Target.
I want to identify the changes in the data that are only present in the source databases and then update the target database according to those changes.

I tried Visual Studio Data Comparison Tool which produced multiple errors. The main issue to be resolved was updating the system-versioned tables(history/temporal tables).

> Error: "Cannot Update GENERATED ALWAYS columns in table xyz"

I have 25 system versioned tables in the database. How can I switch off system-versioning temporarily or I can write another script for handling this situation?

Comment: The documentartion on Temporal Tables explains how to remove it ( `set (system_versioning = off)` ), for easy management build a  procedure you can utilise that controls the system versioning properties as required so you can switch off / resume. Alternatively look at tools that manage this for you such as Redgate Data Compare.

Comment: I tried setting system-versioning = off, but I am still getting the same error message. @Stu

Comment: Drop those columns or don't compare them?